# jupyterbook is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: jupyterbook

I am trying to install [jupyterbook](https://jupyterbook.org/start/overview.html) on Windows 10

I do have Python3.9 installed so at the Dos prompt in c:\Users\kirst\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
I typed

```
py -m pip install -U jupyter-book
```

which placed files in the lib\site-packages folder

but when I type

```
jupyter-book --help
```

I get an error

jupyterbook is not recognised as an internal or external command

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter-book.exe is in the python39\Scripts folder

changing to this folder worked.